# New Regex from literate string

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I don't understand why `` rg = new RegExp(`/${a}.*${b}/`) `` doesn't work below whereas `rg = /\(.*\)/` does work.

```
let a = '\(';
let b = '\)';
let rg;
//rg = new RegExp(`/${a}.*${b}/`); // doesn't work
rg = /\(.*\)/;
let match = rg.exec(`test (regex works) is ok`);
if (match) {
  console.log(match[0]); // -> (regex works)
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because you would need to double escape the `\` in the string.

```
let a = '\\(';
let b = '\\)';
```